# PyQgis does not load a vector layer to form

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I will want create "Hello World" project at PyQgis. I will want to show map on    form.ui from .shp-file, but it does not  download and show.
But it is not loaded and does not appear. It`s value variable "layer" after load .shp
[image]

```
    file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                   "Open Shapefile", ".", "Shapefiles (*.shp)")
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(file)

    # Add the layer
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(file, fileInfo.fileName(), "ogr")

    if not layer.isValid():
      return

    # Add layer to the registry
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer);

    # Set extent to the extent of our layer
    self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())

    # Set up the map canvas layer set
    cl = QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)
    layers = [cl]
    self.canvas.setLayerSet(layers)
```

layer.isValid() = false

map files have extensions:
.cpg
.dbf
.prj
.qix
.shp
.shx

[image]
[image]

[image]

I tried to change. Nothing changed

Comment: You have a semi-colon at the end of this statement, what happens if you remove it, QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer);

Comment: nothing, it is after layer.isValid() = false.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the file variable path format or the shp layer.  Does the shp layer show if you manually add it into QGIS?  Try hard coding the file path to see if that works.  If that works, then add a print statement on the file variable to see if it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I tried to change. Nothing changed.

Comment: screens attached to the end of the answer